# Dictionary to Sparse Vector Python

Tags: python

please help me on this homework:

makeA({0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 9: 1})

the output should be like this:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: "Plz give me teh codes"? What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a list comprehension:

```
def makeA(d, default=0):
    """Converts a dictionary to a list. Pads with a default element

    Examples:

    >>> makeA({0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 9: 1})
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

    >>> makeA({3: 'kos'},'')
    ['', '', '', 'kos']

    """
    maxElem = max(d)
    return [d.get(x, default) for x in range(maxElem+1)]
```

The first line of the function body finds the maximum key in the dict (because `dict` objects yield their keys when iterated over). If the maximum key is 5, you'd need an array of 6 elements [0..6].

The last line uses a list comprehension over a sequence `0 .. maxElem`, and for each value of this sequence, assigns either `d`'s value for this key or 0 if not present.

Comment: `d.get(x, 0)` is shorter and simpler.

Comment: use `max(dic)` instead of `max(d.keys())`

Comment: Thank you very very much, all of you.

Comment: @delnan, AshwiniChaudhary I have applied your comments (and added a doctest). Please remember that SO is a collaborative q&a and you can just edit my post. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do the default value in list comprehension. But I think it's nicer style to let the defaultdict class do it for you. And you get more readable code to boot!! :-)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def makeA(d):
    dd = defaultdict(int, d)
    return [dd[n] for n in range(10)]


print makeA({0: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 6: 1, 9: 1})
```